# jQuery - Auto submit form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to **auto submit** form which flow is like below.

1. **input type = 'file'** should not display.
2. if click on submit button **choose file** pop up should open.
3. after selecting a file form should **auto submit with validation**.

I complete most of this but facing problem while submitting form.

**NOTE** -> i hide **input type = 'file'** using css style.

Here is my HTMLfrom

```html
<form method="post" class="form" action="<?php echo base_url('csv/store'); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile" accept=".csv" style="display:none">
 <br/>
 <input type="submit" class="submit btn btn-primary" value="Import csv"/>
</form>
```

This is my javaScript

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    function validation() {
        //validation here
    }
    
    $('.submit').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#myfile').click();
    });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    function validation() {
        //validation here
        alert('in function validation')
        $('#myForm').submit();
    }
    
    $('.submit').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#myfile').click();
    });
    
    $('#myfile').on('change',function(){
        validation();
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" class="form" id="myForm" action="<?php echo base_url('csv/store'); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile" accept=".csv" style="display:none">
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" class="submit btn btn-primary" value="Import csv"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the submit button, give the hidden `input type="file"` a `<label>` element and style that as a button. This will make it look like a submit button, but will instead prompt the file upload.

Then listen for the `change` event on the hidden file input. This event will be fired every time you upload a file. There you'll want to do validation. If the validation succeeds, manually submit the form with the jQuery `.submit()` method.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function validation(files) {
    //validation here, now returns true for demonstration.
    return true;
  }

  $('#myfile').change(function(event) {
    // Check if files are valid.
    const isValid = validation(event.target.files);
    
    // If the are..
    if (isValid) {
      // ..submit the form.
      $('#myform').submit();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="myform" method="post" class="form" action="<?php echo base_url('csv/store'); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label for="myfile" class="submit btn btn-primary">Import CSV</label>
  <input type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile" accept=".csv" style="display:none">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Emiel Zuurbier, your answer also worked for me but Funky answer is easy to understand and similar as my code.